# Best Scala collection type for vectorized numerical computing

Tags: api, scala, scala-collections, numerical-computing

Looking for the proper data type (such as `IndexedSeq[Double]`) to use when designing a domain-specific numerical computing library. For this question, I'm limiting scope to working with 1-Dimensional arrays of `Double`.  The library will define a number functions that are typically applied for each element in the 1D array.

**Considerations:**

- Prefer immutable data types, such as `Vector` or `IndexedSeq`
- Want to minimize data conversions
- Reasonably efficient in space and time
- Friendly for other people using the library
- Elegant and clean API

Should I use something higher up the collections hierarchy, such as `Seq`?

Or is it better to just define the single-element functions and leave the mapping/iterating to the end user?

This seems less efficient (since some computations could be done once per set of calls), but at at the same time a more flexible API, since it would work with any type of collection.

Any recommendations?

Comment: If you'll got problems with values boxing you may take a look at [debox](https://github.com/non/debox)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your computations are to do anything remotely computationally intensive, use `Array`, either raw or wrapped in your own classes.  You can provide a collection-compatible wrapper, but make that an explicit wrapper for interoperability only.  Everything other than `Array` is generic and thus boxed and thus comparatively slow and bulky.

If you do not use `Array`, people will be forced to abandon whatever things you have and just use `Array` instead when performance matters.  Maybe that's okay; maybe you want the computations to be there for convenience not efficiency.  In that case, I suggest using `IndexedSeq` for the interface, assuming that you want to let people know that indexing is not outrageously slow (e.g. is not `List`), and use `Vector` under the hood.  You will use about 4x more memory than `Array[Double]`, and be 3-10x slower for most low-effort operations (e.g. multiplication).

For example, this:

```
val u = v.map(1.0 / _)   //  v is Vector[Double]
```

is about three times slower than this:

```
val u = new Array[Double](v.length)
var j = 0
while (j<u.length) {
  u(j) = 1.0/v(j)      // v is Array[Double]
  j += 1
}
```

If you use the `map` method on `Array`, it's just as slow as the `Vector[Double]` way; operations on `Array` are generic and hence boxed.  (And that's where the majority of the penalty comes from.)

Answer (score 3):

I am using Vectors all the time when I deal with numerical values, since it provides very efficient random access as well as append/prepend.

Also notice that, the current default collection for immutable indexed sequences is Vector, so that if you write some code like `for (i <- 0 until n) yield {...}`, it returns `IndexedSeq[...]` but the runtime type is Vector. So, it may be a good idea to always use Vectors, since some binary operators that take two sequences as input may benefit from the fact that the two arguments are of the same implementation type. (Not really the case now, but some one has pointed out that vector concatenation could be in log(N) time, as opposed to the current linear time due to the fact that the second parameter is simply treated as a general sequence.)

Nevertheless, I believe that `Seq[Double]` should already provide most of the function interfaces you need. And since mapping results from Range does not yield `Vector` directly, I usually put `Seq[Double]` as the argument type as my input, so that it has some generality. I would expect that efficiency is optimized in the underlying implementation.

Hope that helps.